# How to provide a customized depedency resolving logic?

Tags: spring

Here is my needs:

AbcRequest has a field called requestBody which needs to be autowired. In the following code, if spring can't find a bean qualifier with "requestBody", it will throw exception, but what I need is if can't find, it will inject the default implementation of Body. Basically it's kind of "dependency resolver" having a fallback strategy - first looking based on some name key, if not find, then looking based on the type.

```
@Component
public class AbcRequest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("requestBody")
    private Body requestBody
}
```

Comment: please share your bit more code **@Service**

Answer (score 0):

You can define two references and make the annotated with qualifier not mandatory. Then just add a message to return existing one

```
@Component
public class AbcRequest {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("requestBody")
    private Body requestBody

    @Autowired
    private Body defaultBody

    public Body getBody() {
        return requestBody != null ? requestBody : defaultBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, I have a lot of such properties, can't dup them all twice. Basically I need a way to extend spring container to change its dependency resolving logic. C#'s unity is easy to do this, can't believe spring is so hard